# SSO based on API app and session based app

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails, angular, jwt, single-sign-on

I have two different web portals that use the same Database.
The first one is a legacy web portal built in asp .net and the second one is made using Angular which consumes API's on the backend and uses JWT token based authentication.
Now I want to implement SSO in such a way that a user logs in to the ASP .NET portal and clicks on a button which takes  the user to the Angular web portal without having to login on the Angular App again.
Similarly when the user logs out from the ASP .NET he should be automatically logged out from the Angular app too.
Any ideas how to implement this custom SSO?

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy as both portal sharing same DB.

Just pass any unique token or identifier with button click to another portal.
then you can identify user based on token/identifier and sign-in directly.

Just need to make sure identifier is unique for each user.

Example:

In DB you have user record like:

```
User Id: 1, name: xyz, UUID: 123-123-456
User Id: 2, name: abc, UUID: 123-123-455
```

now while link will have something like this:

`https://somedomain.com/page-path?token=123-123-456`

Comment: This solution poses a huge security risk as anyone can get the token from the url and get access to the portal

Comment: Yes, you are right but you can twist here.
generate UUID dynamically while generating URL form .net side and once validated on other end delete that UUID. 
this way this will be valid for single time only

Comment: you can setup process to auto delete UUID after some interval as well. like after 2 min or 5 min

Comment: If we delete the UUID, how we will authorize each API!

Comment: UUID used for single time authorize, then after you have to use token based authentication for internal authentication like device-token authorization, JWT or OAuth